# Why did Community not roll back an edit that it suspended me for approving?

Tags: support, edits, review-suspension

I recently [approved an edit incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10477678) and my review privileges were suspended with the notice:

> Please take more care in reviewing; you recently approved an edit that's really an attempt to comment

I went and looked at the edit I noticed that it was approved because 3 other users also approved it.

[image]

I figured that since it was found to be a bad edit it would be rolled back, but 5 days later [it wasn't rolled back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34036300/revisions) so I went and did a hack job of rolling it back to before the edit.

[image]

Is this a bug, or are there two separate processes that don't talk to each other?  Obviously someone/something noticed that it was a bad edit and took action against me for improperly approving it, but shouldn't it also be rolled back?

Comment: A mod forgetting to roll back the edit when review banning you wouldn't be a bug.  It'd be a mod forgetting to do something.  It does look like they did just forget to do that though, yes.

Comment: They can both be manually done by mods, who are people.  And people aren't perfect.  Not sure if any automated system exists for either of these things.

Comment: @Servy thanks I didn't realize this was a manual process since I thought Community was a bot, but that is probably me getting confused between the ownership of the edit and the review of the approvals.

Comment: @dstudeba You can be banned automatically, but that would only be for approving an edit that was never a real edit in the first place, and you trying to approve it wouldn't apply it, so there would never be any need to roll it back.  If you're banned from an actual edit that was made by a real person and really applied (or even really rejected) then it was a manual ban.

Comment: @Servy That makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this was my mistake -- I applied the manual review ban but forgot to roll back the edit. Thanks for taking care of rolling it back.